# Should we handle questions about Ubuntu for phones?

Tags: discussion, scope

Ubuntu announced at CES their plans to release [a version of their operating system for phones](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/phone). As it turns out, one of the first phones they intend to officially support is the Galaxy Nexus - an Android phone.

Does this therefore qualify questions about Ubuntu for phones as on-topic for our site? Should we handle them or direct users elsewhere?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My opinion, which I've expressed in the past:

Although the Galaxy Nexus is an Android phone off-the-shelf, I don't think that installing or using Ubuntu for phones is within the scope of our site. Questions related to running Ubuntu *along side* Android (in a chroot environment with VNC, for example) seem okay to me since Android is involved in the process, and we've handled a few here in the past.

Using Ubuntu for phones requires completely **replacing** the Android OS with Ubuntu. At that point I think we've left the realm of Android Enthusiasts and entered into the realm of [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com). We're built around the Android ecosystem, and though the device may have been originally *intended* to run Android, using it for a completely different purpose seems beyond our expertise and our scope. I wouldn't expect a Microsoft support forum to help me install Ubuntu on a desktop because it originally came with Windows - I'd expect an Ubuntu community to help me.

Comment: Interestingly, at [apple.se], asking about putting an Apple OS on non-Apple hardware is specifically _off-topic_.

Comment: @user1: Interesting. I wonder if that's because of the licensing nastiness that comes with Apple's operating systems. Using it on non-Apple hardware is (from what I understand) explicitly forbidden in the EULA, even if you were to, for example, go buy a physical copy of OS X.

Comment: @user1 I guess that is because it is a "hackintosh" question, as explained above by eldarerathis, it is definitely a growing community however. In fact Michael Dell asked Apple if he could sell Dell computers preinstalled with Mac OS, which they denied. Apple is a "closed ecosystem", whereas Ubuntu, Android, are Open Source highly customisable environments. IMHO Ubuntu on a phone should be asked on the Ubuntu site, for one simple reason - it is Ubuntu, doesnt matter which device it is running on

Comment: Oh, I know the whys and wherefores. I was just pointing out how another site in the network handles a very similar situation.